# Can we have a delete review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-delete

Are there any plans to add a delete review queue to Stack Overflow?

We've already [canned the 10k flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue). As a higher-rep user, I'd like to find some queues I can contribute to that others can't.

One of the things I can do is delete things, yet the interface for doing this is inefficient ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1oq0.png)). Can we create a nice review queue for this purpose? The queue would be populated by questions that have at least one delete vote.

Comment: "Clunky"? You think a simple list of questions is "clunky", and the *review queue* is optimal? I need to get some of what you're smoking.

Comment: @CodyGray Absolutely. It frustrates me having to expand that list, open a bunch of links in separate tabs and review things individually. The review queues are much more efficient. I'd like to plough through review tasks without fighting against the user interface.

Comment: I edited to the word "inefficient", perhaps "clunky" wasn't right (or has a different meaning elsewhere in the world).

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148204/can-we-get-some-more-review-queues-questions-with-delete-votes-recently-close

Comment: Hmm, not really. That's just a synonym for clunky. I think a list of questions is far more efficient than the abomination that is the review queue. Yes, you need to click on the links and open them in browser tabs. That is basically how I do everything on the Internet, including looking at questions here. I'm not sure we'll ever agree, though. I feel like I'm "fighting against the user interface" every time I use the review queue. So much so that I've pretty much stopped using it.

Comment: @CodyGray OK, sounds like I won't win you around on this one. But I can only assume others find the review queues just fine, as we don't seem to get many complaints about the interface. And certainly nobody requesting we replace it with a big list of questions. Yet... ;-)

Comment: @ChrisF It seems the conclusion to that question is "Here are some painful ways to do what you want" :-(

Comment: In my opinion, the utility of the review queue is that it basically walks people who are new to reviewing through the process, step-by-step. It gives them instructions, a list of basic choices, and all they have to do is click. I'm not saying we should abolish them. I'm saying that I find them clunky. And when it comes to undeleting questions, I don't think we need training wheels attached. Seems like an experienced moderator tool, not something we need to get more eyes on like close and re-open votes.

Comment: @CodyGray _"the utility of the review queue is that it basically walks people who are new to reviewing etc"_ -- I bet all the ~10K close reviews I made at SO and ~3K delete votes I cast at Programmers so far that this is not so (not _only_ so, to be precise). To me, **queue interface is simply so much more convenient** than crappy delete list. I am using both for quite a long time, I don't need any friggin' training wheels and I compare purely on usability matters (from a perspective of an experienced user)

Comment: @Duncan I've found that Data.SE queries such as http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/207652/ and http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/141131/ are especially useful in trying to track down things that need to be deleted. Not a queue exactly, and still not elegant...

Comment: And a "Convert answer to comment" queue would also probably help the mods.

Answer (score 31):

I don't believe this is a good idea. I've seen a disturbing trend lately where I've come across many highly voted closed questions with useful answers that are being deleted by a list of the same users each time. There appear to be several people who are either coordinating their delete votes via chatrooms or are voting to delete everything that appears in the 10k delete votes tool page.

When I've had to undelete dozens of questions in response to flags about good content being removed, and I see the same names over and over again, I begin to get concerned. It hasn't yet gotten to the point where I need to start sending explicit warnings, but it's getting close to that.

The system already takes care of deleting almost all bad closed questions that need to be removed, and does so on a schedule that gives the user some chance to improve their closed questions. Deletion votes from higher-reputation users should only come on closed questions  that are bad enough to warrant deletion, have no other redeeming value, and are being missed by the auto-deletion system. By design, deleting questions should be harder than closing, so making people have to take conscious action to vote to delete something seems right to me.

Adding yet another review queue for only deleting questions would seem to encourage a higher rate of question deletion, and I'm not in support of that. If you think 10k users won't abuse this queue in the way that other queues have been, I should point out that there are many 10k+ users who have been banned from review over 10 times each for approving spam, vandalism, or other harmful things. They'd continue to abuse review here, only with much more destructive consequences.

Comment: Fully agree. The phrase 'cutting off their nose to spite their face' comes to mind when deleting highly-voted content because it's not 'pure'.

Comment: Is "good content" in the way of "popular upvoted content" or actual interesting Q&A's?

Comment: @Braiam - I'm generally referring to useful, detailed information that provides a valuable resource to others. I'm talking about more than heavily upvoted bikeshed arguments.

Comment: Ok, that's fair.

Comment: People are definitely coordinating votes in the PHP chatroom.  The chat messages are nothing more than "[tag:delv-pls] [tag:cv-pls] (link-to-question)"  No case for why a vote is appropriate.  Often no comment left on the question either.  And seem to have a history of wacky ideas about the purpose of closure (such as: can't delete an upvoted answer we don't like; therefore delete the question).

Comment: Vote coordination will not be prevented by keeping the interface awkward. I understand your concerns about triggering more good content to be deleted, but I really don't think a better interface will cause that to happen to a worrying degree. It might also encourage more terrible posts to be deleted, which isn't a bad thing. A queue also provides the opportunity to mark something as not worthy of deletion, which may remove it from the queue. This option isn't available with the simple question list - stuff remains until it inevitable attracts the remaining necessary votes.

Comment: Users will always misbehave, regardless of the usability of the interface. I don't think the two issues should be conflated.