# Enhance the "Delete list" of the moderator tools

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

Users with at least 10k reputation gain access to [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). This tool covers lots of data around Stack Overflow: [new answers to old questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319952/1743880), [recently protected questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273882), but also [a sort-of deletion / undeletion list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days).

That last page contains a list of posts having pending delete votes, pending undelete votes as well as recently deleted and undeleted posts. This is a great way to monitor, for example, posts getting wrongly deleted / undeleted, posts that should be kept but with pending delete votes, or posts that are missing votes in order to be rightfully deleted / undeleted. One of the very first problems is that [this isn't a very well-known page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278173/1743880) and I believe we can make that page more widely known if we make it show the data I feel people are interested in seeing. The following is a screenshot of the page (arbitrarily focused on the questions with the most and recent delete votes):

[image: Screenshot of the page]

To summarize, this is what the page is already showing:

- Link to the post with the title, either of the question or of the question the answer belongs to. Questions and answers are distinguished by the font size of text of the link (bigger for questions);
- Current count of delete votes (the number on the left, (with no tooltip and/or indication by the way));
- Number of delete votes that would be needed at this time to delete the question (the number on the right, (with no tooltip and/or indication as well)).
- It is sorted by the number of current delete votes descendingly (as far as I can tell).
- There is a way to restrict on time spans (only show today events, or at most from the past 30 days).

In order to scan problematic behaviour or just the list of posts, this page is lacking some love. [A *review queue* was asked for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269544/1743880), [multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148204) [times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345134/1743880) but let me emphasize that I am not asking for a complete new queue here, just various small enhancements with regard to the already existing tool, with the intention of making it more usable. Enhancements that (I hope) shouldn't need an entire rewrite. Quite notably, this is what I would like to be able to do on the page:

- Show next to the post the first tag on the question (i.e. the tag having the most questions). Ideally, [an ability to filter by tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267174/filter-10k-tools-by-a-tag). This would make it a lot easier to quickly eyeball the list for posts on which I might have an opinion, and disregard those I know nothing about.
- What's the score of the question? Because, for example, if it's positively scored, I want to determine if the vote is warranted.
- Does it have lots of views? Again, a delete vote on a highly viewed question may need [more attention / edit love](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/1743880).
- Does it have answers? If it doesn't, and is negatively scored, I could trust the community for voting, [the roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) for deleting it automatically and move on.
- Understand what the numbers written represent with the help of tooltips.

I'm not sure how this information should be presented on the page. Perhaps even more information could be added and the general layout should change, but since that page is only intended to be used by already experienced users, I think it can stay somewhat crude, and adding the first question tag, the score and the number of answers after the link would be enough. As an example, consider this way of presenting (which is actually comes from a userscript enhancing [cv-pls chat messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262359/1743880)):

[image: Picture of the enhanced cv-pls requests from SOCVR]

It shows the tag, the breakdown of up/downvotes, the number of views (v), in a simple, yet, complete manner. This same way of presenting could work for the wanted information here as well.

Comment: Here are some related improvement requests for that page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124420/improve-the-recently-deleted-tool https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92979/restore-the-10k-ability-to-see-all-closed-deleted-posts-in-a-list https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274100/in-10k-tools-show-posts-that-are-automatically-deleted-when-a-users-account-is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44101/10k-most-delete-votes-list-dont-show-questions-i-cant-vote-for https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94442/10k-deleted-list-not-showing-full-range

Comment: I also find that page entirely useless for <20k rep, since the posts there are usually closed less than 2 days ago, or even answers :(

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345134/the-10k-tools-could-do-with-some-love